# Android Action Bar with editText on separate line in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

So began researching how to create an action bar with an autocomplete text view for search.  Most of the solutions I've found come close to what I'm looking for however they all seem to be focused on cramming any and additional views added to the action bar on one line.

Further complicating this, is the fact that this is all located in a view pager fragment whose parent activity already has an action bar.   Thus using the setSupportingActionBar call with a Toolbar throws an illegal state exception.

Not sure if what I am accomplishing is actually supported but here it goes.

**The end result I am looking for is this**

[image]

**Here is what I wrote**

*custom view containing the autocomplete text view named autocomplete.xml *

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search_text_view"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_blue"
        android:background="@drawable/white_edittext"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*here is the code in my fragment used to setup the action bar*

```
private void initializeActionsBarWithAutocomplete(){
        ActionBar actionBar = ((MyParentActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.default_title));

        View autoCompleteView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.autocomplete, null);
        mSearchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) autoCompleteView.findViewById(R.id.search_text_view);
        mSearchTextView.setAdapter(mTypeAheadAdapter);
        mSearchTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mSearchTextView.addTextChangedListener(this);

        actionBar.setCustomView(autoCompleteView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

**What I end up getting is this**

[image]

So assuming what I'm trying to do is possible, and I'm at least on the right track, what exactly is going wrong here.  I assumed that having the custom view match parent would force the textview to take up its own line and expand the size of the action bar accordingly.  That is clearly not the case.  I looked at some articles that allowed you to set the height of the action bar explicitly but from what I can comprehend, that method will result in the same appearance with a bunch of white space under views in the action bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Toolbar` widget in XML and customize it as per your needs.

**Here is an layout of `Toolbar` containing `AutoCompleteTextView`:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                cardview:cardElevation="0dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/search_text_view"
                        android:paddingTop="15dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                        android:paddingRight="20dp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search_blue"
                        android:background="@drawable/white_edittext"/>

                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**In your `JAVA` code try this:**

```
Toolbar mToolBar;
ActionBar mActionBar;
AutoCompleteTextView mSearchTextView;

private void initializeActionsBarWithAutocomplete(){

    // ToolBar
    mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // AutoCompleteTextView 
    mSearchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) mToolBar.findViewById(R.id.search_text_view);
    mSearchTextView.setAdapter(mTypeAheadAdapter);
    mSearchTextView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mSearchTextView.addTextChangedListener(this);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

    // ActionBar
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.default_title));
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: How would I apply the custom action bar (programmatically I'm assuming), for example by modifying my 'initializeActionsBarWithAutocomplete' method?

Comment: So a further complication is that this is occurring in a fragment whose parent activity already has an existing action bar.  I will update the question accordingly

Comment: Marking as accepting answer as this was the gist of the problem and got me 90% of the way to solution